# Multi-Part Request

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

I have an application which handles Multipart Request in below format.

```
POST .... HTTP/1.1 
. . . 
Accept:multipart/form-data 
...
---boundary123 Content-type:application/octet-stream content-Disposition: 
form-data filenale="payload.txt" name="someuniquename" 
... 
[paylaod content](this is in xml format) 
---boundary123 content-type:application/json content-Disposition:form-data 
name="someuniquname1" 
{ 
... 
ID:"999"
}
```

---boundary123

and here is my my controller part.

```
@Restcontroller 
Class A{ 
@RequestMapping(value = "/a/b/c", method = RequestMethod.POST,  consumes= 
MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, 
produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public @ResponseBody static void MyController(@RequestParam("file") 
List<MultipartFile> files) {
}
```

Is this controller can parse both parts by identifying content-type(xml and json, no order) if I am receiving single multi-part file.If not Can you suggest format of controller for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following to get the FormData in your Controller.

```
RequestMapping(value = "/yourPath", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Object upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    //Get your form fields...
    final String ID= request.getParameter('ID');
    //and so on......

    //Get your files.
    Iterator<String> iterator = request.getFileNames();
    MultipartFile multipartFile = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        multipartFile = request.getFile(iterator.next());
        //do something with the file.....
    }
}
```

Comment: What does Request and response contains?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Response parameter is not needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this would be to use the part boundry *name* with the `RequestPart` annotation:

```java
@Restcontroller 
Class A {

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/a/b/c",
            method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public @ResponseBody void myController(@RequestPart("someuniquname") SomePojo xmlPart, @RequestPart("someuniquname1") SomeOtherPojo jsonPart) {
        // ...
    }
// ...
}
```

Comment: Its Takes 2 parameter and I am sending only 1 multipart file with two MIME attachments  and also @RequestPart("someuniqname") Name could be anything.Do you think this really works?